# oAuth2.0 authentication in C++

Tags: c++, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a desktop application in which I need to make a user authentication with oAuth2.0.

I looked at the Facebook example but it doesn't really correspond to what I have to do or I don't understand it well.

In fact, I create an O2 instance:

```
O2* o2Auth;
o2Auth = new o2Auth(this);

o2Auth->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
o2Auth->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
o2Auth->setRequestUrl(REQUEST_URL);
o2Auth->setTokenUrl(TOKEN_URL);
```

But I don't understand how to authenticate the user with the user name and password. Which function do I have to use to do that?
In Facebook example, there is:

```
if (argList.contains(OPT_OAUTH_CODE)) {
    // Start OAuth
    fbdemo_.doOAuth(O2::GrantFlowAuthorizationCode);
} else if (argList.contains(OPT_VALIDATE_TOKEN)) {
    fbdemo_.validateToken();
}
```

where argList is the parameters given to the application but they are not the user name and password.

In the tweeter example, there is :

```
oxTwitter_->setUsername(username);
oxTwitter_->setPassword(password);
```

but I didn't find the equivalent in O2.

I think I have to use things like GET and POST functions in the OSRequestor class, but how to link a OSRequestor instance to my O2 instance?

So what do I need to send user name and password to do the authentication with O2?

Comment: The point of OAuth is that you don't ever see the users password. They only use those to authenticate to Facebook, then the OAuth token is used to prove to your application that they have been authenticated. You should never be directly handling the users Facebook password.